# Process Scheduling (SRTF)-

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

Consider a uniprocessor system with four processes having the
following arrival and burst times:
[image: TABLE-1]

(i) Calculate the average waiting time and also the average
turnaround time if shortest (remaining) job first (SJF) scheduling policy is used with pre-emption. Assume that the context
switching time is zero. Note that in SJF, if at any point there
is a tie, then the job that arrived earlier will get priority.

---

my CALCULATION:-

[image: TABLE-2]

ready queue:
[image: TABLE-3]

Am I going correct??

*reference* :_- JRF-CS-CSB[ISI,2018 question]

Comment: Yes . But this question may be rejected.

Comment: They say that not to ask this type of question. You have to specify where you are stuck , or what thinking is right and what is actually happening there etc. And also dont ponder over it i have written this just to complete specified minimum letters to do a comment ( otherwise i was going to write just Yes ) ;)